# How to send unidirectional requests via soap?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I have an `cxf` autogenerated `soap` client from `wsdl`.
There is a method `void logout(String hash)`.

When I run this method, the client waits for the response of the server. Sometimes this can be very long as the server seems to perform some tasks on a logout request.

Question: how can I invoke this method without waiting for the response (and even not caring for a response)?

Comment: Is that a good idea? How will you know that the request was successful if you ignore the response? Is your question more related to UI asynchronicity, i.e. the UI is held up by the server?

Comment: I don't care if the response is successful, and it's a command line tool without UI.